# highlight row when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I wanted to highlight the entire row when check box is being checked and remove highlight when unchecked. I just generate only a toggle checkbox. thanks your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function draw_equipment($equipment)
{
    $equipment_name = $equipment['img_link'];
    echo "<div style='text-align:left;width:90%'>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' class='toggleCheckbox'>";
    echo "<img src='img/$equipment_name' alt='$equipment_name' width='90px'/><br/>";
    echo $equipment['equip_type'];
}
`
```

Comment: Where is the row? If you want to achieve it using jQuery, bind the `change` event handler. then use DOM traversal method to get _row_

Comment: a fiddle or code snippet would be better

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/65fzdx0u/